# How to run a php file on a rented server using cronjobs

Tags: php, cron

I have a domain. In said domain, I have a file tucked away that randomizes a table. `public_html/games/gamename/scripts/random.php` **obtained this from the file manager software of the company I rent the server from**

I want to setup a cron job that will simply run this file once every 30 minutes. I've never used CRON before.

My questions:

> A: Is there a better way to confirm that the address of the file is the correct one for this action.
>   B: What is the cron code I would use to run the file?

Thanks!

Comment: 0/30 * * * * php path\to\file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer --

I was just setting one up in cPanel and here's what I got to work:

php -f /home/cpanel_username/public_html/path/file.php

works great for me.

Comment: @Dagon: irrelevant whether those does or not, since wget would be run on OP's own machine and hitting the server to run the script...